# How to structure a Flask app like in Django?

Tags: python, flask

I have switched from Django to Flask for a project and am a bit lost how to setup a similar structure like in Django.

In my flask example everything works fine in a single file but the moment I even try to pull the models into its own class, I run into a cross-reference issue and can't solve it.

**F11.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**models.py**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
```

The problem already starts here with `db.Model`. `db` is instantiated in the main `F11.py`, so how do I access it? If I just import it I would get a cross-reference error.

Comment: https://github.com/fogleman/HelloFlask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually put the initializations in `__init__.py` under the main project folder.

`__init__.py`

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
import myproject.views
import myproject.models
```

`models.py`

```
from myproject import app
from myproject import db

class User(db.Model):
```

`runserver.py` (one level up)

```
from myproject import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

In general I like to structure my application in such a way that you do not need to `import app` in any of the files. For my current project the only file that imports the app is a file called `manage.py` which does little more than allow me to do certain things using Flask-Script.

A nice feature that many Flask extensions have is the `init_app` method. This allows you to instantiate extensions of you app without requiring the app object.

Let's say you set up the database called `db` in a file called `db.py`. This may look something like

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Let's further say that you set up the app in `__init__.py`. This file may look something like

```
from flask import Flask
from app.db import db

app = Flask(__name__)
db.init_app(app)

# ...
```

Now your database is initialized for your Flask application, and you will not have problems with circular reference when you import the db directly via `from app.db import db`, for examples in your `models.py`.

For my views I often revert to Blueprints instead of using the `@app.route('/')` methods. Just like the database, blueprints can simply be imported in your `__init__.py` file and be registered to the app there.